# Android: Get a list of files from a web directory

Tags: android, listview, file

I'm trying to get a list of files from a web directory, and display them in a listview. Upon clicking, it will open the file shown. How can I achieve this? This is on Android, and I would prefer to be compatible with version 2.1 and later.

The directory does not contain an index file, and will properly display the list of files when one browses the directory. I just need a way to retrieve them and display them in a listview.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start with a [Java HTML parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) to comprehend the list. Then you can construct your listview. It would probably be easier to have a server-side script generate the list in a simple format (ie. use PHP to generate an XML listing)

Unless the files are all of a known type, it may be tricky to "open" them. That is, they need to be passed to the correct application for opening.

Your question is not really fleshed out.